# Magic Jack - Safely Remove Hardware Never Works!

Tags: usb, magicjack

We use [MagicJack](http://www.magicjack.com/5/index.asp) regularly. However, after our conversations, if we right click on the USB icon (on System Tray) and say Safely Remove Hardware, we always always get the message

"The device 'generic volume' cannot be stopped right now.

I have tried looking up the forums and they suggest that we kill the process magicJack.exe via Task Manager but I am not too comfortable doing that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it cannot be stopped is something is still using it.  That'd probably be magicJack.exe.  Yes, you can safely kill this with task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just follow their instructions? If you aren't using it then killing the process shouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the tray icon for ejecting drive, go to My Computer, right click on the drive and select "Eject". Works in most of the cases because it forces any programs using the drive to stop usage.  If still the issue persists,then its safe to kill the process in task manager as it will close the open handles related to application.